# 2 div position with "min-height" and "top" property

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs with     min-height    . The first one has a top property of 470px. I want the second div to display staright underneath the first div without any space between. I have also tried display: block and putting the divs into a table, neither of which worked any better. Here is te css:

```
#content {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 470px;
  background: #1C1C1C;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content2 {
  width: 100%;
  position:;
  top:;
  background: #333333;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="content">
        <p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
    </div>


    <div id="content2">
        <p>texttexttexttexttext</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add complete HTML also

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: the position: absolute of the first div is taking it out of the flow of the page, so the second div is just ignoring it. You could put them both in a parent div, and make that position absolute instead?

Comment: Can you change the HTML?

Comment: thank you i have managed to resolve the issue by changing both my div positions to relative, replacing the top:470px in the first div with margin-top, and changing the positions of my content above the divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you absolutely position an element you take it out of the document flow so you can't really have something come right after it unless you absolutely position it as well.  I changed it to just use a top margin to put it where you want it.  If you need elements in that top 470px then you can absolutely position those elements.

And the borders I put in are for illustration only.

```css
#content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 470px;
  background: #1C1C1C;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: #333333;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">First DIV</div>
<div id="content2">Second DIV</div>
```

Comment: Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32144082/2025923) with `absolute` positioning, but changing the HTML structure it can be done

Answer (score 1):

Because `#content` is positioned *absolutely*, you cannot do this without changing the HTML structure.

You can add a container element to the `div`s which is positioned `absolute`ly with the same `top` as of `#content1` and add the two `div`s inside the container without `position`.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 470px;
}
#content {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #1C1C1C;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#content2 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #333333;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <p>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
    <p>texttexttexttexttext</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your HTML, but this is my wild guess.

Try this:

```
<style>
#content {
   width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content2 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;

}
</style>

<div id = "content">
<p> Content - 1 </p>
</div>
<div id = "content2">
<p> Content - 2 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `min-height` not `height`, that is _minimum_ height, not fixed it can also be increased